# PHP Regular Expression Does Not Work

Tags: php, regex

I've been trying the next regular expression

```
$pattern = '/([0-9]{1,2}[.]{1}([a-z|A-Z|0-9]+[\s]*)+)/';
```

in order to detect the following occurences in a text : [number].[text],
for example : 1.text text text
For the next text`"test number one  1.first 2.second"` the result is

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(9) "1.first 2" [1]=> string(9) "1.first 2" [2]=> string(1) "2" }
```

Where is the problem in the regular expression I wrote?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: can you please put the string you applied the regex & what you expect to have ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do:

```
\d+[.][\w\d\s]+?(?=$|\s\d+[.])
```

It will match all the 3 occurrences in this text: `"1. text test 2. some more22  3. and more"`

Comment: Hey , thanks for the answer ! It's working ,but I don't understand what does the ?(?=$|\s\d+[.]) part mean, could you please explain it ? Thanks again.

Comment: It is a positive lookahead. It is not included in the result. In this example it tries to detect where the next match starts so it cuts the current one there. You can find more detailed explanation here http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: I've checked the pattern you've offered but it doens't match the occurences in the example you've brought...

Comment: I can run it here http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/ and it matches all tree. This is PHP

Comment: array(1) { [0]=> string(12) "1. text test" }

Comment: Do you use preg_match_all?

Comment: I now use preg_match_all and it works just fine ! What was the problem with only preg_match ?

Comment: It is not a problem, it finds only the first occurrence. This is that way it is supposed to work. If you want all you should use preg_match_all.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the plus at the end, which means you can match things after the space. It should be:

```
$pattern = '/([0-9]{1,2}[.]{1}([a-z|A-Z|0-9]+[\s]*))/';
```

Comment: " the plus at the end, which means you can match things after the space" Match things? the plus stands for "once or often", are you talking about the same thing?

Comment: Thanks for the answer @alestanis , but now the output is
array(3) { [0]=> string(8) "1.first " [1]=> string(8) "1.first " [2]=> string(6) "first " } , which still does not include 2.second and still includes "first" which does not fit the pattern.

Comment: @Jonast92 The plus applied to the group containing letters or digits followed by spaces, so it was the plus' fault if the regex matched `1.first 2`, the `2` being the `thing`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$pattern = '/\d\.\w+/';
$str = "test number one 1.first 2.second 3.third 4.xyz 5.abcd";

preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $m);

print_r( $m );
```

The output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1.first
        [1] => 2.second
        [2] => 3.third
        [3] => 4.xyz
        [4] => 5.abcd
    )

)
```

**is that what you need ? I'm not sure that I get well what you need to match so please try to explain it a bit more**

You can say for example:

> I would like to match ***x numbers followed by . followed by n letters***

or something like that